# VBA to Hide specific sheets listed in one sheet named "Summery"

Tags: excel, vba

I tried based on the following code. It mentioned below. Actually I want to hide a particular list of sheets which were given in one sheet named "Summery" from range (7,8) to (40,8). The following is the code:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    rc = 40
    For r = 7 To rc
        sheet = Sheet37.Cells(r, 8)
        Sheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next
End Sub
```

But it was not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sheet = Sheet37.Cells(r, 8)
```

Use

```
Set sheet = Worksheets(Sheet37.Cells(r, 8))
```

You should also consider adding error handling in case the listed sheet name does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a Toggle button, I assume you want to unhide it on the second click? So maybe try this:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim shList As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summery")
    shList = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("H7:H40"))

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, shList, 0)) Then
            sh.Visible = Not sh.Visible
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```